Work on Nonlinear ODE by Implicit Euler Method
Suppose the problem is $dx/dt=f(x,t)$ with initial value $x_0$. By Implicit Euler Method, $x_{n+1} =x_n+hf(x_{n+1},t_{n+1})$. If $f$ is linear, we can explicitly express $x_{n+1}$. If it is nonlinear and given a value of $\varepsilon>0$ (error tolerance), we perform several iterations $x_{n+1}^{(j)} = x_n+hf(x_{n+1}^{(j-1)},t_{n+1})$ for $j=1, 2, \cdots$ and $x_{n+1}^{(0)} = x_n+hf(x_n,t_n)$, and so on until we have $\left |x_{n+1}^{(j)} - x_{n+1}^{(j-1)}\right |<\varepsilon$. Then, $x_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^{(j)}$.

Given a system of ODEs $dx/dt = f_1(x,y,t)$ and $dy/dt = f_2(x,y,t)$ with initial values $x_0$ and $y_0$. By Implicit Method,
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + hf_1(x_{n+1},y_{n+1},t_{n+1}),\quad y_{n+1} = y_n + hf_2(x_{n+1},y_{n+1},t_{n+1}).\tag{1}$$
If the ODE system is linear, then we can express $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ in $(1)$ explicitly. If it is nonlinear and given a value of $\varepsilon>0$ (error tolerance), how do we find a solution for $x_{n+1},y_{n+1}$? This is an iteration of
$$x_{n+1}^{(j)}= x_n + hf_1(x_{n+1}^{(j-1)},y_{n+1}^{(j-1)},t_{n+1}),\quad y_{n+1}^{(j)}= x_n + hf_1(x_{n+1}^{(j-1)},y_{n+1}^{(j-1)},t_{n+1}),\quad j=1,2,\cdots$$
and $x_{n+1}^{(0)}= x_n+hf_1(x_n,y_n,t_n)$, $y_{n+1}^{(0)}=y_n+ hf_2(x_n,y_n,t_n)$ until $\lVert(x_{n+1}^{(j)},y_{n+1}^{(j)}) - (x_{n+1}^{(j-1)},y_{n+1}^{(j-1)})\rVert<\varepsilon$?

Yes, that is correct. You might want to use some Newton-like method to accelerate the fixed-point iteration, that is with some matrix $J$ close to the Jacobian of the right side of the ODE $\dot X=F(X,t)$ solve
$$
(I-hJ)X^{(j)}=X_n+h(F(X^{(j-1)},t_{n+1})-JX^{(j-1)})
$$
This will reduce the linear convergence rate of the iteration. Of course if $J$ is always the exact Jacobian at the current point $(X^{(j-1)},t_{n+1})$, it will instead increase the order of convergence to quadratic, but usually it is not worth the effort. $J$ and a factorization of $I-hJ$ can  be kept constant over several steps.
The model for linear convergence is the geometric sequence, the difference of two sequential terms is not always a good predictor for the distance to the limit. This may become a problem if the step size is too large.
